# core data adding a new field to an existing sqlite table

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I have an sqlite table that I'd like to add a new field to. Would I add the new field directly in sqlite or does the Core Data model change the sqlite table itself?

I'm stuck for some reason right now w/ adding a new field to the db table. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *never* access the sqlite database directly when using Core Data.

Add the field programmatically with Core Data methods (work on the model), or if using the graphical modeling tool (xcdatamodel file), add it there.

You might need a model migration model, too. Maybe check the [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) document for *Versioning*.

Comment: so, you could have an empty sqlite database and create the table and fields with core data?

thanks for your response.

Comment: Now are you using sqlite or Core Data?